# How can I get a Dell XPS 8300 to boot from some medium?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, dell-xps, windows-10-preview

I recently attempted to install Windows 10 Technical Preview on my Dell XPS 8300. Before the installer there was a blank partition, some windows7 partitions, and an ubuntu install. Issues occurred while deleting and reformating the empty partition in the Windows 10 installer, and I was forced to turn the computer off. Now, when I turn the computer on the BIOS loads but I cannot proceed to the F12 Boot Options menu, the F2 Setup menu or any of the installed operating systems. The BIOS just freezes, and it I can hit F12 or F2 at that point to highlight / select either option, but neither menu actually loads.

Because I am unable to select a USB or DVD to boot from, I am unable to boot from a gparted live CD or anything else to repair my hard drive.

**What can I try to do to fix this?** I am guessing that deleting a partition on the Windows 10 Installer did not damage the actual BIOS, but might have caused issues in the hard drive that are making the BIOS throw errors. I am considering pulling out the CMOS battery to try to reset the motherboard, but I do not want to do that unless I absolutely have to as it is a dangerous procedure in my opinion.

EDIT: It appears someone has encountered an issue with almost the exact same symptoms on a different machine here: [Dell latitude not booting](https://superuser.com/questions/834601/dell-latitude-wont-boot-past-bios-after-windows-10-update)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this on a PC at work and the only thing I could do was remove and replace the battery. The POST isn't completing which means something has been changed.

1. Make sure your PC is powered off
2. Fully unplug your power source
3. Leave the PC for 10-15 mins to let any power running around the motherboard dissipate
4. Remove the battery fully
5. After a minute or so put it back in
   The CMOS is now back to factory and will hopefully boot.

IF YOU DO THIS WHILE THE PC IS POWERED YOU **WILL** FRY IT!

If you still have problems comment this and I'll step through what we can do to get you up and running.